# How to develop the data source webpart in VS 2010?

Tags: web-part, data-view-web-part

I want to develop the content datasource webpart, which should fetch the data from SPLists and provide it to other requesting webparts. how to build this content datasource web part ? What i need basics ?

Comment: How to accept if nobody satisfied me in answering. and really i don't want to fake accept.

Comment: when I take a look at your questions and answer, some of them have answer without comment, or you saying "that does not solved your problem". I can't imagine that there is actually zero answer which is the correct answer... or explain why when you are not satisfied with an anwser

Comment: cool buddy ... see i have accepted :) ...! now i am expecting answers from you specially... :) he he he he

Comment: glad to see you accepted :)

Comment: to help, can you precise want is your goal? I'm not understanding what you meant by "develop"

Comment: see, i want to implement the webpart who can fetch the data from configured list and make available the fetched data to requesting webpart. can we do that ? can i inherits CQWP pragmatically in c# ?

Comment: there is not content datasource webpart. There is either a SPDataSource control, or the content by query webpart. You can simply use SPD to put a list view. Is there anything that the standard web part does not do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an existing "Content Query Webpart". Just add an xsl file in your webpart settings to change the layout. To use data from other webparts, you should look at this [msdn-tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff597538.aspx), how to connect webparts.